# Set defined by $xy-zw=1$

Tags: algebraic-topology, euclidean-geometry

This should be an easy question, but I found it ungooglable and not obvious to visualize...

What geometric object is defined by the equation $xy-zw=1$ in $\mathbb R^4$? And what is the homotopy type of the complement?

Comment: By trivial identification with the subset of the space of $2\times2$ matrices, it is just $SL(2)$. I know not much on it, but this may help you google it.

Comment: You mean $\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: Think before asking. Yes, sorry, it is just $\mathrm{SL}_2\ \mathbb R$, which is homotopy equivalent to a circle. Thus the complement has fundamental group $\mathbb Z^2$ and second homotopy group $\mathbb Z$. Thanks.

Comment: Taking complements does not respect homotopy equivalence in general. For example, $\mathbb{R}^2$ admits both a point and $\mathbb{R}$ (as a coordinate axis) as contractible (hence homotopy-equivalent) subsets; for the former the complement is homotopy equivalent to $S^1$ but for the latter the complement is homotopy equivalent to two points.

Comment: I see, but all contractions I have used involve whole vector spaces... Does this still not work?

Comment: No. The complement of a circle in $\mathbb{R}^4$ is connected and the complement of $xy - zw = 1$ cannot be (see my answer).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's $\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})$, of course! As a "geometric object" it may equivalently be realized as the unit sphere $x^2 + y^2 - z^2 - w^2 = 1$ in $\mathbb{R}^{2,2}$, which exhibits it (or maybe one of its connected components?) as a homogeneous space for the orthogonal group $\text{O}(2, 2)$. In particular it can be given the structure of a [pseudo-Riemannian manifold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-Riemannian_manifold).

The complement of the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^{2, 2}$ has two connected components
$$X = \{ (x, y, z, w) : x^2 + y^2 - z^2 - w^2 > 1 \}$$
$$Y = \{ (x, y, z, w) : x^2 + y^2 - z^2 - w^2 < 1 \}.$$

$X$ deformation retracts via the straight-line homotopy $(x, y, (1-t)z, (1-t)w)$ to $\{ (x, y) : x^2 + y^2 > 1 \}$, which is homotopy equivalent to $S^1$.

$Y$ deformation retracts via the straight-line homotopy $((1-t)x, (1-t)y, z, w)$ to $\{ (z, w) : z^2 + w^2 > -1 \}$, which is contractible.

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to visualize a 3-dimensional hypersurface in 4 dimensions.  But perhaps this animation may help, showing cross-sections at different values of $w$.  Note that these are hyperbolic paraboloids except at $w=0$ where you have a hyperbolic cylinder.

http://www.math.ubc.ca/~israel/problems/surf2.gif

Comment: I used Maple...