# the manifold of $ D=\{x,y,z,w \mid xw-yz \le 0\}$

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, manifolds, parametric, symplectic-geometry

What geometric object $({{x,y,z,w}})$ is defined by the equation $xw-yz\le 0$ in $\mathbb R^4$? Using parametrics, can we describe this manifold? Is it possible to prove a diffeomorphism between this geometrical object and others?

Comment: Objects in $R^4$ cannot be visualized... And I do not think there is a name for this set if you infer something like sphere of dim 3

Comment: @dmtri I mean can I use some parametrics to describe this geometric object to prove some diffeomorphism?

Comment: One possible interpretation is as $D=\{(a,b)\in\mathbb{C}^2\mid\Re(ab)\le0\}$ by setting $a=x+iz$ and $b=y+iw$. I don't know if it's useful.

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud then use complex analytical tools?

Comment: No clue. You can certainly try.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The set $D$ is not a manifold; in fact, it's not even a manifold with boundary. It has nonempty interior (the set of all points where $xw-yz<0$), so if it were going to be a manifold with boundary it would have to be $4$-dimensional, and thus its boundary would have to be a $3$-manifold, which it's not. The interior, however, is a $4$-manifold, because it's an open subset of $\mathbb R^4$.

Here's how to see that $\partial D$ is not a $3$-manifold. It's the set where $xw = yz$, and I claim this set is actually a ***cone on a torus***. By that I mean it is homeomorphic to the quotient of the space $\mathbb S^1\times\mathbb S^1 \times [0,\infty)$, with the entire set $\mathbb S^1\times \mathbb S^1 \times \{0\}$ collapsed to a point. Consider the map $F\colon \mathbb S^1\times\mathbb S^1 \times [0,\infty) \to \mathbb R^4$, given by
$$
(x,y,z,w) =  
F(\theta,\phi,r) = (r\cos\phi + r \cos\theta, r \sin\theta+ r\sin\phi,  
r\sin\theta- r\sin\phi, r\cos\phi- r\cos\theta),
$$
where $\theta$ and $\phi$ are interpreted mod $2\pi$, so they represent points on a circle. A straightforward computation shows that $F$ maps into $\partial D$ and collapses the entire set  $\mathbb S^1\times \mathbb S^1 \times \{0\}$  to the origin. A little more work shows that its image is all of $\partial D$ and it doesn't make any other identifications, so it descends to the quotient to show that $\partial D$ is homeomorphic to the cone I mentioned above.

This cone is not a $3$-manifold. The proof that it's not is a little technical, but here goes. Every point in a $3$-manifold has a neighborhood $U$ homeomorphic to a $3$-ball, and therefore when the given point $p$ is removed from $U$, the punctured set $U\smallsetminus \{p\}$ is simply connected. But if $U$ is any neighborhood of the origin in $\partial D$, when you remove the origin you get a set homeomorphic to an open subset of $\mathbb S^1\times \mathbb S^1 \times (0,\infty)$, and containing a torus of the form $\mathbb S^1\times \mathbb S^1 \times \{\varepsilon\}$ for some small $\varepsilon$.  The set $U\smallsetminus \{0\}$ retracts onto this torus. Since a retract of a simply connected space is simply connected, while the torus is not, this shows that no punctured neighborhood of the origin in $\partial D$ is simply connected. Thus $\partial D$ is not a $3$-manifold, and $D$ is not a manifold with boundary.

Comment: $ D_{\delta}=\{x,y,z,w \mid xy-zw \le \delta\}$ when$\delta<0$ or when $\delta>0$, I proved it is actually a manifold but when delta=0 it is not?

Comment: I think this one is related to$ \{(x,y,z,w)| x^{2}+y^{2}-z^{2}-w^{2}\le 0\}$ check this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160624/set-defined-by-xy-zw-1

Comment: sorry, may I ask what if it's $xy-yw\le 0$, this time a manifold? I am extremely unfamiliar with those topologies

Comment: @Mclalalala: Yes, if you replace $0$ by $\delta\ne 0$, then you get a manifold. If you want to ask about a completely different inequality like $xy-yw\le 0$, you should probably post a separate question.

Comment: can you actually elaborate a little bit more in details why the above bijiection is indeed a homeomorphism. I've already understand the other parts of the answers! Thxu for you patience and help!

Comment: @Mclalalala: It's based on a fundamental result about quotient maps -- if $q_1\colon X\to Y_1$ and $q_2\colon X\to Y_2$ are quotient maps that make the same identifications, then $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are homeomorphic. See Theorem 3.75 in my _Introduction to Topological Manifolds_, 2nd edition.

Comment: sorry if just less then 0, $xw-yz<0$, what's the shape of that?

Comment: @Mclalalala: Well, the simplest parametrization is just the identity map, because it's an open subset of $\mathbb R^4$. But it's diffeomorphic to a product of a solid torus with $\mathbb R^+$, or more precisely $D^2\times\mathbb S^1\times\mathbb R^+$, where $D^2$ is the unit disk.

Comment: @Mclalalala: Such a diffeomorphism is given by mapping $((u,v),\theta,r)\in D^2\times\mathbb S^1\times\mathbb R^+$ to the point obtained by replacing $(\cos\phi,\sin\phi)$ by $(u,v)$ in the formula for $F$ above, namely $F((u,v),\theta,r) = (ru + r \cos\theta, r \sin\theta+ rv,  
r\sin\theta- rv, ru- r\cos\theta)$. (Note that my original formula for $F$ was wrong; it's corrected now.)

Comment: @Mclalalala: Yes, it is more complicated. It's not always possible to describe such a space in terms of more familiar objects -- sometimes it just is what it is.